# Quadratic endogenous variables in R, instrumental variables

Tags: r, regression, instrumental-variables

As part of ongoing research I'm to test a certain model on some data. One of the questions asked (c.f. one of the hypotheses) involves estimating the quadratic term of an independent variable (in R). The problem is that there is concern that the variable is endogenous and maybe should be instrumented. Estimating the linear endogenous variable and including its fitted values into my main model (while correcting the standard errors) is not the problem. My question is how I can include the quadratic (instrumented) term of that endogenous variable into my main regression equation?

Assume my main linear model (in R):

**Y ~ X1 + X2**,

where X2 is the endogenous variable and X1 is some exogenous control. Then the model that corrects for the endogeneity of X2 through 2sls method:

**Y ~ X1 + X2hat**,
where **X2hat ~ Z1 + X1**,
and Z1 is some exogenous instrument that influences Y through X2.

I read somewhere that in order to include the quadratic term of the 'instrumented' endogenous variable (X2hat), I would need to estimate the regular quadratic term based on the same regressors (i.e. Z1 + X1) as the linear 'instrumented' endogenous variable.

Main quadratic model (in R):

**Y ~ X1 + poly(X2,2)**,

where poly(X2,2) creates orthogonal linear and quadratic terms of X2 (through QR decomposition). Then the model that adjusts for endogeneity through 2sls would be (assuming what I read is correct):

**Y ~ X1 + X2hat + (X2^2)hat**, 
 where **(X2^2)hat ~ Z1 + X1**

Is the method I'm using the correct one? Or should I approach this problem in a different way? Is this even possible or would you expect problems with multicollinearity?

.

Comment: This is an interesting question because for identification sake, if you have 2 endogenous variables you require 2 exogenous instruments. My thinking is that the rule is the same here even though your second endogenous variable is just a reconstruction of the first. 

Have you tried independent regressions:
Y ~ X1 + X2hat
Y ~ X1 + (X2^2)hat

Comment: @Jason, what whould the use be of have to seperate main model regression? Isn't the coefficient of a quadratic term only valid if the non-quadratic term is also included?

Comment: Sorry. You can have Y ~ X1 + X2hat + X2^2. The variation of the squared term doesn't have to be exactly identified in order to get a good estimate on 'X2'.